# Is it normal for Chromium to ask to open KWallet right after startup?

Tags: linux, kde, chromium, password-management

I have a Kubuntu 14.04 system, on which Chromium, after showing its window on startup, results in KWallet dialog popping up, asking to open the wallet. This makes me suspicious, because this happens even before I try to open a page which might require any passwords. Moreover, even if I rename my `~/.config/chromium`, after the clean startup Chromium still wants to open KWallet.

Is it normal behavior for Chromium? Why could it want to open KWallet even though there are no plugins nor pages requiring any passwords?